# Pipeline status on Repos/File page

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure Devops, in Repos/Pipeline page, there is pipeline status badge(right next to fork and clone buttons)

[image: pipeline badge]

How is this badge work? I can't find any information about this feature.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? "How is this badge work?" is not an answerable question.

Comment: I believe I can't. For example, if a branch is built by two pipelines. One of them will fail and one will succeed, what will be in a badge? I'm looking for some documentation etc, rather than answer for a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is toggled on at the **Get Sources** page in your build pipeline. Please refer to below pic.

If the **Report build status** is checked, then the build status will be displayed on source repo.

If unchecked, the build status will stop updating on source repo.(the last status will still be displayed, only not updating )

[image]

Comment: thanks. What will happen if some brach will be built by multiple pipelines when some of them will fail and some succeed?

Comment: i think it will display the status according to the last pipeline run